# htop. Тормозит сервер. Загрузка по ползунку не выше 30%

Tags: ubuntu

Медленно работает VDS Ubuntu 16.04. (1 ядро 2ГБ памяти)
Смотрю htop: ползунок нагрузки на ядро процессора не поднимается выше 30%, хотя Load Avarage показывает значение 4.

[image: htop]

Вопросы:

1) Как понять, что ядро процессора VDS загружено на 100%?

2) Почему Load Avarage может принимать значение больше единицы? Я так понимаю если загрузка 100%ная, то Load Avarage должен быть около единицы.

Comment: load average это не только про процессор, но и про ввод-вывод например

Comment: как-то можно отдельно посмотреть "нагрузку на ввод-вывод"?

Comment: `iostat` пакет `sysstat`

Comment: `iotop` тоже хорошо.